# Updating ObservableObject value dismisses view

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine, navigationview

In my app I use `EnvironmentObject` which I use to store data objects and the user profile, I use this to make changes throughout the app via various settings.

I also have a `ViewModel` `ObservableObject` for passing data between views.

I am trying to set data values from one `Observable Object` to another in a child view of a `NavigationView`, one which is in the environment of the app.

However when doing the following it keeps to dismissing to the root `NavigationView`. Does anybody know why this might be ?

**ObservableObject**

```
class UserStore : ObservableObject {

   var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

   //MARK: Properties
   @Published var profile: User? {didSet{didChange.send() }}
   @Published var editingNote: Note? {didSet{didChange.send() }}

}
```

**ObservableObject**

```
class NoteViewModel: ObservableObject {

  var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

  @Published var note: Note? {didSet{didChange.send() }}

}
```

**View**

```
@EnvironmentObject var userStore: UserStore
@ObservedObject var model: NoteViewModel 

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
          self.userStore.editingNote = self.model.note
        }) {
          Text("Edit note")
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Would you prepare minimal reproducible example of your situation?